# Kivy : Difference between a View and a Layout

Tags: kivy

I'm trying to get a better understanding of how Kivy classes interact and when to use what classes. I've found with the documentation several examples of [Layouts](https://kivy.org/docs/gettingstarted/layouts.html) and [Views](https://kivy.org/docs/search.html?check_keywords=yes&area=default&q=View).

As far as I understand, [View inherit from FloatLayout](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.abstractview.html) but I'd like to understand what they offer. Can a view be used for a part of the screen or is it intended to take the whole screen ?

If I wanted to finish this sentence, what would it be : "A view is a layout with/that ..." ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Layout has a specific meaning, a Widget that imposes some position and/or size on its children.

View isn't used in the same consistent manner, its name appears in widgets doing a number of different things. In the end they're all Widgets and can be positioned and sized however you like. For instance, there isn't much relationship between ScrollView and StencilView, they're just names reflecting (I suppose) that the Widgets affect visibility somehow.